# Is the question about the mean of a random variable wrong?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I am stuck on the following problem:

Find out the mean of the random variable $X$ such that $X$ has the following probability density function.

$f(x)=1-|x|\text{ if } |x|<1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

**My try**
I am wondering if $f(x)$ is even a PDF. We know that if $f(x)$ is a PDF, then it should satisfy $\int _{-\infty } ^{\infty} f(x) dx=1$.

But I dont think $f(x)$ satisfies it.
If $f(x)$  is not a PDF, then how can we find out its mean?

Am I missing something or the question is wrong? Can someone please clarify?

Comment: It's a typo. The inequality should be $|x|<1$.

Comment: With the hint of Andreas it works: $\int_0^1 1-x \ dx +\int_{-1}^0 1+x \ dx=1$.